# Allow Dialog edit form for multiple rows in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working with a React application. To simplify, there is a list component that displays a table of records by looping over the array data. On each row I have an edit button. When I click the edit button I want to open a Dialog (material-ui modal) form component that will allow editing of the data in that row.

```
const SensorList = props => {
  const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = React.useState(false);
  const [pollutant, setPollutant] = React.useState(0);
  const handleOpenEdit = (pollutant) => {
    setPollutant(pollutant);
    setOpenEdit(true);
  };
  const handleCloseEdit = () => {
    setOpenEdit(false);
  };

  return (
    <Grid className={classes.sensorList}>
      <Typography variant="h4">Sensors:</Typography>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell align="left">Actions</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">Pollutant</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">Path</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Start Date</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {props.monitor.pollutantConfig.map((sensor, idx) => {
              return (
                <TableRow hover key={idx}>
                  <TableCell align="left">
                    <FormGroup>
                      <div>
                        <FormControlLabel
                          control={<Switch size="small" checked={!sensor.suspended}  {...checkbox({
                            name: 'sensorActive_' + idx,
                            onChange: toggleSensor
                          })} />}
                        />
                        <IconButton aria-label="edit" size="small" onClick={() => handleOpenEdit(sensor.pollutant)}><EditIcon fontSize="small" /></IconButton>
                        <IconButton aria-label="delete" size="small" onClick={() => deleteSensor(sensor.pollutant)}><DeleteIcon fontSize="small" /></IconButton>
                      </div>
                    </FormGroup>
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">
                    <Typography>{sensor.pollutant}</Typography>
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">
                    <Typography>{sensor.path}</Typography>
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">
                    <DataStartDateField sensorIndex={idx} monitor={props.monitor} />
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      {props.monitor.pollutantConfig.length > 0 &&
        <EditSensorForm open={openEdit} onClose={handleCloseEdit} monitor={props.monitor} pollutant={pollutant} />
      }
    </Grid>

  );
};
```

For some reason the function `handleOpenEdit` is only called upon loading. I cannot hit a breakpoint inside it where it should be setting the `pollutant` variable when you actually click it. Thus, that property is never set when the Dialog opens.

What am I missing to allow this scenario?

Comment: Where are you calling handleOpenEdit ?

Comment: The onClick of the edit icon button.

Comment: Did you check the devtools, pollutant definitely doesn't change when you call  handleOpenEdit ? ... if so can you try onClick={handleOpenEdit(sensor.pollutant)}

Comment: I changed the onClick to be `onClick={() => { handleOpenEdit(sensor.pollutant)}}` (extra curly braces and now it updates the pollutant on click.